# Visualizing Feature maps: IndexError: too many indices for array

Tags: python, matplotlib, error-handling, conv-neural-network, index-error

Following this tutorial I am trying to visualize feature maps.

My model looks as follows:

```
model.summary()
Model: "model_3"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_5 (InputLayer)            [(None, 224, 224, 3) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
efficientnet-b0 (Functional)    (None, 7, 7, 1280)   4049564     input_5[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_4 (Flatten)             (None, 62720)        0           efficientnet-b0[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
branch_0_Dense_16000 (Dense)    (None, 256)          16056576    flatten_4[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
branch_1_Dense_16000 (Dense)    (None, 256)          16056576    flatten_4[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
branch_2_Dense_16000 (Dense)    (None, 256)          16056576    flatten_4[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
branch_3_Dense_16000 (Dense)    (None, 256)          16056576    flatten_4[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
branch_4_Dense_16000 (Dense)    (None, 256)          16056576    flatten_4[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
branch_5_Dense_16000 (Dense)    (None, 256)          16056576    flatten_4[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
branch_6_Dense_16000 (Dense)    (None, 256)          16056576    flatten_4[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
branch_0_output (Dense)         (None, 35)           8995        branch_0_Dense_16000[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
branch_1_output (Dense)         (None, 35)           8995        branch_1_Dense_16000[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
branch_2_output (Dense)         (None, 35)           8995        branch_2_Dense_16000[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
branch_3_output (Dense)         (None, 35)           8995        branch_3_Dense_16000[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
branch_4_output (Dense)         (None, 35)           8995        branch_4_Dense_16000[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
branch_5_output (Dense)         (None, 35)           8995        branch_5_Dense_16000[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
branch_6_output (Dense)         (None, 35)           8995        branch_6_Dense_16000[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_4 (Concatenate)     (None, 245)          0           branch_0_output[0][0]            
                                                                 branch_1_output[0][0]            
                                                                 branch_2_output[0][0]            
                                                                 branch_3_output[0][0]            
                                                                 branch_4_output[0][0]            
                                                                 branch_5_output[0][0]            
                                                                 branch_6_output[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
reshape_4 (Reshape)             (None, 7, 35)        0           concatenate_4[0][0]              
==================================================================================================
Total params: 116,508,561
Trainable params: 116,466,545
Non-trainable params: 42,016
```

I now would like to visualize the layer with index 10: `10 branch_0_output (None, 35)`

```
3 branch_0_Dense_16000 (None, 256)
4 branch_1_Dense_16000 (None, 256)
5 branch_2_Dense_16000 (None, 256)
6 branch_3_Dense_16000 (None, 256)
7 branch_4_Dense_16000 (None, 256)
8 branch_5_Dense_16000 (None, 256)
9 branch_6_Dense_16000 (None, 256)
10 branch_0_output (None, 35)
11 branch_1_output (None, 35)
12 branch_2_output (None, 35)
13 branch_3_output (None, 35)
14 branch_4_output (None, 35)
15 branch_5_output (None, 35)
16 branch_6_output (None, 35)
```

I followed the code stated in the tutorial, preprocessed the image and I now would like to plot the 35 (?) feature maps of this layer:
I used the code in the tutorial and amended the square number, here it is 1 but I tried several:

```
# plot all 35 maps
square = 1
ix = 1
for _ in range(square):
    for _ in range(square):
        # specify subplot and turn of axis
        ax = pyplot.subplot(square, square, ix)
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_yticks([])
        # plot filter channel in grayscale
        pyplot.imshow(feature_maps[0, :, :, ix-1], cmap='gray')
        ix += 1
# show the figure
pyplot.show()
```

Independent on what number I tried I got this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-4c1f464f6978> in <module>()
      9                 ax.set_yticks([])
     10                 # plot filter channel in grayscale
---> 11                 pyplot.imshow(feature_maps[0, :, ix-1], cmap='gray')
     12                 ix += 1
     13 # show the figure

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Can someone help what I have to amend?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error shows `too many indices for array` in line 11. This is happening because you are passing indices incorrectly in the feature maps. Here you are trying to plot 35 maps in a 1*1 grid as you have given square = 1.

Suppose you need to plot `64` maps, then we will take `square = 8`, then the output will be a 8*8 grid.

Comment: Ok, so, that means in my case it should be `feature_maps[0:17, 18:35]`? Or what would you recommend?

Comment: I have edited my answer please refer and see if this works.